# Inserir e buscar dados no banco de dados por usuário com Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Preciso salvar informações no banco de dados por usuário logado. Ou seja, quando o usuario logar, tudo o que ele fizer vai salvar no banco de dados desse login.

Ou seja, quando o usuário X logar, tudo o que ele salvar no banco vai ser referente a ele (usuário X).

Como proceder nesse caso em Laravel? Pensei em ser por ID, Auth, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Caro amigo eu sugiro você a criar uma tabela de `logs` onde você vincula pelo `id` do usuário à atividade executada pelo mesmo. Exemplo:

1. Criar um **Model** para a tabela de Logs.
2. Criar um **Helper** que você possa chamar em qualquer
   **Controller**.
3. Criar descrições padrão para cada atividade seja ela um `insert`,
   `update` entre outras...

Exemplo **Model**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SystemLogs extends Model
{

}
```

Exemplo **Helper**:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Helpers;

class LogsHelper
{
    public function saveLog($acivity){
      ...
    }
}
```

Exemplo **Controller**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Helpers\LogsHelper;

class MyController extends BaseController
{
  public function add(){
    ...
  }

  public function save(){
    ...
  }

}
```

Claro que não irei programar para você, estou só passando uma ideia de registro de atividades de usuários bem simples. Neste seu caso em especifico você pode salvar na tabela de logs o nome da tabela alterada, o id do registro criado, alterado ou deletado vinculado ao id do usuário. Isto é muito útil em auditorias.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou! Testei essa lógica com o que eu havia pensado e deu certo, obrigado!

Comment: @brunoelyg teria como compartilhar seu código? eu entendi a lógica mas como sou iniciante no Laravel não consigo sair do lugar. :/